# File reference with Github Actions

Tags: json, bash, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy a file via bash to an external endpoint using github actions.

This file is located up two directories from where the action exists. Locally I can get to it using the path `../../src/indexer/templates/library.json`. I've tried using the workspace as a root but the file is never actually set to the `json` variable. Current step:

```
- name: Deploy template to cluster
  run: |
    json="<${{GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}/src/indexer/templates/library.json"
    echo "deploying template to cluster ${{ inputs.environment }}"
    curl -X PUT \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -u "${{ steps.secrets.outputs.USERNAME }}:${{ steps.secrets.outputs.PASSWORD }}" \
    -d '$json' \
    "${{ secrets.CLUSTER_URL }}";
```

Is there some syntax I'm missing here, or is there a better way to do this in a separate step?

Answer (score 0):

try the `working-directory` keyword to change to the directory before running your command

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

```yaml
- name: Clean temp directory
  run: rm -rf *
  working-directory: ./temp
```